# How to call a method of childB caused by an event in ChildA using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React for my project and pretty new to using it. Below is the problem I am facing.

I have the following component structure:

```
<Parent>
  <ChildA></ChildA>
  <ChildB></ChildB>
</Parent>
```

I would like to have the following feature: When a button is clicked in Child A, I want a method to be executed in ChildB.

Can you kindly let me know how we can achieve that in ReactJS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but there's a video up here which calls out architecture issues in larger apps, and one of them is components in the view layer directly manipulating other view layer components. https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5429-going-big-with-react It recommends a different architecture, which takes advantage of the fact that React makes it easy to re-render views.

Comment: I agree with Douglas here. The more react-friendly way to solve this problem would be to have the button click event update some state higher up in the component hierarchy and then let React re-render everything.

Answer (score 1):

There are two direct answers to this.

1. Use event emitters.  In ChildA's click handler you emit a "whatever" event.  ChildB had registered a listener for the "whatever" event, so its handler for that event is called.
2. Use refs.  You pass a function to ChildA as a prop `<ChildA onWhatever={fn}>`, and put a ref on ChildB `<ChildB ref="b">` and in the function you pass to ChildA you do `this.refs.b.method()`.

However, this is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  The real good solution probably lies in you taking a step back and thinking "when the button is clicked, what observable change should happen?" rather than "what method should be called?".

Answer (score 0):

Parent component should contain:

```
handleClickA: function(){
    this.refs.b.AClicked()
},
render: function(){
    return <div>
        <ChildA onClick={this.handleClickA}></ChildA>
        <ChildB ref='b'></ChildB>
    </div>
}
```